# Adding target to window.location

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if possible to add a **target="_blank"** to my java script code. I am trying to make it so opens in new window/tab

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#site").on('click', function(){
    window.location = "http://www.someone.com/";    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try with `window.open("http://www.someone.com/")`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#site").on('click', function(){
    window.open("http://www.someone.com/","_blank");
});
</script>
```

Example for [reference](http://jsbin.com/unevus/40/edit?html,js,output)